# secured web service php/json

Tags: php, ajax, json, web-services, security

I'm currently creating an admin platform with a lot of website, these sites can publish and get data from the admin platform.

There is a way to secure this and only accept publish/get from these sites ?

**EDIT**

Actualy I use some ajax scripts with JQuery in a test website. And it's not safe at all.

Comment: I have just finish the admin platform and for my test I use some ajax by using jquery to publish/get my data but it's not safe isn't he ? ^^

Comment: You can't say "I use ajax so it isn't safe". Ajax can be perfectly safe. Use authentication as @Tadeck says to be sure you only accept messages from who you want.

Comment: How can we tell what's safe and what isn't if there's no code or explanation?

Comment: @CodeCaster that's what I want to do :)

Comment: @nickb I'm currently use something like http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ so there is no interest to show the code. I juste search a good way to secure interaction with my admin platform.

Comment: not enough information to answer this question.  You must be clear and specific.  As it stands the security concerns you should should be worried about is badgers breaking though the dry wall and damaging your servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use **authentication** ([see more](http://www.duke.edu/~rob/kerberos/authvauth.html)).

In case you have no idea what scheme you can use, you can use eg.:

- [OAuth](http://oauth.net/),
- ID + password pair,
- authentication based on IP (" *if you are connecting from IP of X, you seem to be X* "),

Did it shed some light on the issue? Did it help?

Comment: Thanks, at first I thought of a solution based on IP but a PHP script can detect the source of an ajax query ?

Comment: @Awea: If you are asking about authentication mechanism for AJAX, then I suppose this is not a good idea to rely on IP. The reason for that is: 1) the connection will be established by client (browser), so the IP will not be the same as site's IP, 2) the HTTP referrer address can be changed in multiple ways and sometimes unavailable,